# Can I use multiple enchantments?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, xbox-360

When I destroy something in the enchantment table that has multiple enchantments, can I then enchant another item with those enchantments at the same time?

Comment: what do you mean by group enchantments?

Comment: A Item that has more than one enchantment, for example the nightingale armor has frost resistance and stamina is increased. Those enchantments are on the same item. That's what I mean.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To enchant an item with multiple enchantments, you must have the extra effect perk. This allows you to enchant an item with two different enchantments. Some enchantments have two parts, see [here](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Enchanting_(Skyrim)) for a list of enchantments, however disenchanting an item with two different enchantments will not allow you to add both enchantments as one enchantment to another item.

Comment: @AwbraCadabra no problem. also seeing as you are new to the site, you can click the check mark next to answers that solved your problem, and once you get enough rep, you can also upvote answers that are helpful to you

Comment: Dragonrage did a good job answering, but you should know that your specific example, nightingale armor, can't be disenchanted. Most unique armors and weapons have unique enchantments as well. With the extra effect twin souls perk, however, you could make a duplicate of the enchantment using two generic ones, with nightingale armor being Fortify Stamina and Resist Frost.